# datepicker with different style than activity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-datepicker

I have activities with custom style, I want my activity with a custom title bar so I created below style:

```
<style name="costum_titlebar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/titlebar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/titlebar_size</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/costum_titlebar</item>
</style>
```

In manifest I use:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
```

In the activity I use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.setting_activity_titlebar);
```

So far it's good and works fine, I have activity with my custom title bar.
Now I want to use datePickerDialog. The problem is that dialog looks old:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

I also have this style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

So I used it to create DatePickerDialog like this:

```
new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.AppBaseTheme, this, year, month, day);
```

But the theme won't apply.

Just for a test,  I create a second app with default style and just one button to open date picker, so the datepicker
Looks like what I want. Both apps have `android:minSdkVersion="8"`

I think the problem is with custom titlebar, so how I can get my custom titlebar and datepicker with desired style?

**EDIT:**

I Changed `android:minSdkVersion="11"`
with
 `<style name="datePickerTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DatePicker"></style>`
   and
`new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.datePickerTheme, this, year, month, day);`

But the Result still is the same.

Comment: Theme holo is supported from API level 11 and above you can`t apply it below 11

Comment: @UsmanKurd: i know that, but as you can see in second app with android:minSdkVersion="8" and android:Theme.Light, the theme applied without problem, i can post the .apk to you

Comment: @UsmanKurd: Ok I tested that. the second app looks old on pre 11 api, and look new on newer api. but this won't happen to my first app, it looks old on both apis.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is little late but I walked into this topic while I was searching something else about DatePickers.

Add this to the custom theme you are using:

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
```

This will override the parent theme you are using and result as a different looking DatePicker.

You will need to create the dialog with this custom theme.

Example of my theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
</style>
```

Comment: For those less familiar with themes, if the activity in which you want to use the datepicker with the desired style doesn't have a theme, you'll put a custom theme in styles.xml, using code in the above format, and in the entry for that activity in the manifest, you'll add the line `android:theme="@style/<Your.Theme>"`, replacing Your.Theme with whatever you've called the theme in styles.xml, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                                                   android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
                                                   ondateSet, year, month, day);
dateDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

This is for showing white color light background Date picker Fragment.