# How to fix DatePicker Design

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, android-datepicker

I'm having issues with the datepicker design. I'm having different design when I'm seeing it on eclipse screen and when I run it on emulator it shows me different design. Screenshots and code are below.

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/added_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

Code which I'm using in `values/styles.xml`. If I don't use this code I get a whole different datepicker.

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
```

**Eclipse screenshot:**

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

**Emulator screenshot:**

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the Android OS version you are running: the later is from 4.0 (or 3.x holo) and up, the the former is 2.x and below. The style is dependent on the os version: instead of relying on the sdk, you might use a third party library (where the style is defined and not dependent on the os version: look here https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=date+picker for what you might want.

Note you can change the style to reflect a particular os version in the preview, by looking for for the Android icon with the number next to it, and selecting which os version you want the preview to reflect.

If you don't want to use a third party library, you can force the style of the datepicker by rewritting the theme style, for reference check this post out: [datepicker with different style than activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835126/datepicker-with-different-style-than-activity)

Comment: OS can't be the problem because same datepicker is working on another app in same OS

Comment: i have tried other OS for this and still same issue

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use a third party library to get whatever style you want (or apply styles to the date picker yourself). So another app on same os can either have same or different style: they might have used a third party library instead of the stock datepicker widget. In other words, this *is* the result of the os version.