# how to change the style of datapicker in android html5 apps

Tags: android, webview, widget

In my android app, I use a `WebView` to load an HTML page. When the element

```
 <input type="date">
```

is clicked, a `datapicker` will show up. Is there any way to change the `style` of the `datapicker` widget that is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom theme

Add this to the custom theme you are using:

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
```

This will override the parent theme you are using and result as a different looking DatePicker.

You will need to create the dialog with this custom theme.

Example of my theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
</style>
```

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835126/datepicker-with-different-style-than-activity

Comment: @android:style/Widget.DatePicker can I change  it  to my own style?

Comment: <style name="appTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
       <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/datepicker</item>
    </style>  
    <style name="datepicker">
        <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor">#121413</item>
    </style>   here's my code,it seems doesn't work