# A single line of code destroyed my project. How to repair?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So before, the AndroidManifest.xml had a part like :

```
...
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity ...
```

And I added a line.

```
...
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:DatePickerDialog="@style/CustomDialogTheme" >
        <activity ...
```

After I pressed the run butten, many errors appeared. This is how it looks now :

[image: screenshot]
[(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbZr.png)

If I try to delete that line and run again, Android Studio will just undo my delete and show the same errors. What to do?

Comment: Restart Android Studio

Comment: I did. Same thing.

Comment: clean and make your project

Comment: You mean to create a new project and add everything back? My project is pretty big. It would take me a lot of time.

Comment: `clean` and `rebuild` under build option in Android Studio

Comment: I pressed the clean button and after it finished the rebuild button. Errors are still there.

Answer (score 0):

`android:DatePickerDialog` is not a property of `<application />`. Remove that line of code and find the right place. Probably something in a style xml.

Comment: @FlabiAndrei I don't know where it belongs, but what is it supposed to do? Custom theme like http://stackoverflow.com/a/23760194/995891 ?  Somewhere in `res/values/` are styles for your app that contains things like that.

Comment: I tried to add a custom theme for the DatePickerDialog. I added that line to link it with the new theme. And after i added it you can see what ahppend.